# How to install windows updates on multiple clients using YUM on CentOS server

Tags: windows, centos, updates, yum

I need to do a installation of windows updates (OS and Microsoft Security Essentials) on multiple clients using Cent-OS Server. I'm not very familiar with Linux systems and I cant find an appropriate tutorial On the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give OPSI a try, this is an OpenSource Deployment Solution which works on CentOS:

http://www.opsi.org/

This is an integrated system to deploy full installation as well as simple updates or rollouts.

Answer (score 0):

`yum` installs RedHat/CentOS/Fedora RPM packages on RedHat/CentOS/Fedora systems. It doesn't have anything to do with Windows. It doesn't understand `exe` files or anything like that.

I'm not even sure where to begin to understand what the question you are actually trying to ask is... unless your question is really just as confused as it sounds and you are failing to understand the difference between package managed linux systems and Windows systems.

Comment: I do understand that. The reason I mentioned YUM its beacuse of this link to [linux questions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/wsus-equivalent-for-linux-4175418214/) refer to the 5th answer made by Ilesterg user. He mentions there that you could used YUM through a ssh service. But I dont fully understand how it works or if it is even possible.

What I need to do is to install windows updates on multiple clients from a CentOS server

Comment: Im trying to find a free alternative solution for [Nitrobit update server](http://www.nitrobit.com/index.html)

Comment: That link was talking about managing linux machines not Windows ones. I've never heard of Nitrobit but it looks like it is a WSUS replacement. yum is not that. I don't know of other products that do this either.